# Is there any way to create or delete workspaces in AML studio using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-machine-learning-service

I am working on a prediction model and am about to use the azure machine learning studio resources. The main operation is to create a workspace on azure ML studio through Powershell. I would like to operate my workspace through the command line. Is there any way to develop and operate the ML Studio workspace through Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the requirements, there is no procedure developed to create/delete workspaces through PowerShell in machine learning studio. For reference of creation of workspaces, you can check the below link and the point to be noted is we can create/delete workspaces using ***Az***

Here is the table link to check PowerShell support table

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/machine-learning/classic/powershell-module

[image]